# Protect deletion of ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-database

Is it possible to ensure that `ForeignKey` can't be deleted?

The best example is on `UserProfile`:

```
class UserProfile(Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField('User',on_delete=models.CASCADE ...)
```

And there is a signal which creates a `UserProfile` for given `User` right after `User` object is created.

I want to be sure that nobody can delete `UserProfile` because every `User` has to have one `UserProfile`.

I tried `on_delete=models.PROTECT` but it doesn't allow `User` to be deleted instead of `UserProfile`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django prevent delete of model instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492666/django-prevent-delete-of-model-instance)

Comment: to delete `user` you first should delete `profile`, how do you plan to do it?

Comment: @DušanMaďar I want opposite. When User is deleted then it's UserProfile is deleted too. I want to protect deleting UserProfile without previously deleting User.

Comment: @BearBrown Hmm, thats true... didn't think about that this way...

Comment: @BearBrown Maybe to do that in one transaction.

Comment: i don't know but you need think about `condition` for two way of the deletion.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding two arguments to the model, `null=True` and `on_delete=models.SET_NULL` so it would look like:

`user = models.OneToOneField('User', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)`

Answer (score -1):

I don't know where I have read, and I don't have the example code for it, 
But you need to use pre_delete signal for preventing the deletion

pre_delete: signal will be called whenever the delete operation is initiated on you UserProfile model, so you can do whatever you want here.

`django.db.models.signals.pre_delete` on UserProfile model

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_delete

class UserProfile(Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField('User',on_delete=models.CASCADE ...)

def your_receiver_function(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
                  if not instance.user:  //if the user is not already deleted don't delete userprofile
                        return False   

pre_delete.connect(your_receiver_function, sender=UserProfile)
```

Comment: your answer look like a comment.

Comment: @Bear Brown, I just updated my answer, please correct it if there is any error.

Comment: now it is not like a comment, but i don't sure it is right way for OP